# Define implementation of websocket interface in Jboss 7.4

Tags: java, websocket, jboss, wildfly

Following the jBoss 7.4 documentation I can define a websocket with the required annotations

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/helloworld")
public class MyService {

    @OnMessage
    String sayHello(String name){ ... };

    @OnOpen
    void helloOnOpen(Session session){ ... };

    @OnClose
    void helloOnClose(CloseReason reason){ ... };

}
```

I would like to have the contract of that websocket in an interface in an external repository, and add that dependency to the project in which I have the implementation.

So in this scenario I would have the chat-api dependency in which I implement the interface

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/helloworld")
public interface MyServiceInterface {

    @OnMessage
    String sayHello(String name);

    @OnOpen
    void helloOnOpen(Session session);

    @OnClose
    void helloOnClose(CloseReason reason);

}
```

And my implementation will use this interface

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyServiceInterface {

    @Override
    String sayHello(String name){ ... };

    @Override
    void helloOnOpen(Session session){ ... };

    @Override
    void helloOnClose(CloseReason reason){ ... };

}
```

But if I do this, Wildfly is not handling the websocket and it does not work. (you can see the problem that I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77014109/websocket-is-not-handled-correctly-in-jboss-7-4/77027555#77027555))

Is there any way I can set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Javadoc it doesn't seem possible:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html:

> The annotated class must have a public no-arg constructor.

Comment: Also, annotations from interfaces are not inherited.

Comment: Every class in java gets a public no-args constructor implicitly by default

Comment: @WillTatam not pertinent here since we are talking interface